# Extracting Specific Text From column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and I'm trying to extract the string that has the ABC followed by it's numbers.

| Description |
| --- |
| ABC12345679 132465 |
| Test ABC12346548 |
| Test ABC1231321 4645 |

I have tried:

```
data['extract'] = 'ABC'+data['Description'].str.split('ABC').str[1]
```

But its giving me what it comes after on instances that there's more text after the ABC* like so:

| Description |
| --- |
| ABC12345679 132465 |
| ABC12346548 |
| ABC1231321 4645 |

And I need the column to only contain data as following:

| Description |
| --- |
| ABC12345679 |
| ABC12346548 |
| ABC1231321 |

Any assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex to extract the necessary part of the string.
Here we are checking for atleast one [A-C] and 0 or more[0-9]

```
data['extract'] = data.Description.str.extract(r'([A-C]+[0-9]*)')
```

or (based on need)

```
data['extract'] = data.Description.str.extract(r'([A-C]+[0-9]+)')
```

**Output**

```
    Description             extract
0   ABC12345679 132465      ABC12345679
1   Test ABC12346548        ABC12346548
2   Test ABC1231321 4645    ABC1231321
```

Comment: what if the combination is not ABC but instead lets say FCS?

Comment: you can either replace [A-C] with [FCS] or you can replace [A-C] with [A-Z] to include all alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on this, but off the top of my head, you could further `split(' ')` to get rid of the rest.

```
df['extract'] = 'ABC' + df['Description'].str.split('ABC').str[1].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

Output:

```
            Description      extract
0    ABC12345679 132465  ABC12345679
1      Test ABC12346548  ABC12346548
2  Test ABC1231321 4645   ABC1231321
```